# How to check all not index pages of a website?

Tags: web

Actually I am working on a music website and   I want to know how to check not index pages on google of website? Please suggest me some tips or tools that help me to check all pages that are not index on google.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just google Google's database and looking for something not in it, but you can create a sitemap ([Google's How-To](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668)), and use [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) to submit it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but is there any way to check pages that are not index

Comment: @SachinKumar, when you added a sitemap, Google will tell you how many pages you submitted and how many of them are already in their index, but I do not know another method.